# Using xsl:if to check the value of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check if the node `<Type>` is either "Debit" or "Credit"

so that I can transform the information from just credit card information into Debit or Credit transactions.

any suggestion????

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. Can you post samples of the input XML, the XSLT you have tried and the wanted output XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `xsl:if` is for "if A do B else do nothing". Use `xsl:choose` (with `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise`) for "if A do B else do C".  Otherwise we do need a more specific example of what you mean.

Comment: Thank you 
<xsl:choose>
<xsl: when test="contains(Type,'Debit')>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose> 
It worked perfectly thanks for all the comments and answers even though my qustion wasnt that descriptive (sorry).

Answer (score 1):

I particularly like using xsl:choose in most situations. It provides the most flexibility. I also would use a variable outside the template for type.

Variable code (belongs outside templates):

```
<xsl:variable name="$type">
    <xsl:value-of select="//type" />
</xsl:variable>
```

xsl:choose code (belongs in a template):

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$type='credit'">
        <xsl:text>Type is credit card</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when text="$type='debit'">
        <xsl:text>Type is debit card</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Type is neither debit or credit card</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Couldn't you shorten that code to <xsl:when test="attribute::Type[text()='Credit']"> or somesuch? In my experience, XSL interprets an empty node-set as false and a node-set of 1+ as true. This may not be reliable however.

Comment: @Tom W:  I like to use variables.. this is just my opinion: I see it as better coding practices. This is because if you need to use this text a thousand times, but all of a sudden a part of the path needs to change, it only needs to be changed once in the variable, instead of a thousand times in all the places the test was used. No? Interested in what you think.

Comment: That's a fair counterargument. It would depend on the context it was used; I would naturally assume that for very many repeated operations, using variables would slow down the XSL processing engine; but your argument for reusability is a good one. If it was used in a lot of different places then a variable is probably a better choice. I tend to prefer brevity where it's appropriate.

Comment: @Tom W: How much do you suppose it would slow down the processing engine? Just curious for future coding of xsl :)